# Url Rewrite in apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I am trying to rewrite urls so that whenever I type say /foo.html, I want the extension of the file to be hidden, so that on the address bar i get to see only /foo . I have tried searching and used rewritecond expressions in .htaccess file of apache server but the url is not getting changed in the address bar. 
One more thing I have observed is the browser displays the content of my foo.html file when i type either /foo or /foo.html **even** when I remove **.htaccess** file.

I am using apache2 on ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: You are off topic but even if your question gets moved to a more appropriate site you should try to show us what you did otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule to your `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

To remove multiple file extensions use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried the same its not working still. I feel there is something else in my setup which is conflicting. I still keep on getting the content of the page foo when i type either /foo.html or /foo . 
The url on the browser still shows /foo.html when i type /foo.html which I want to get changed to /foo.
One more thing is that even after disabling mod_rewrite module, the above is true i.e. when I type /foo, the content of foo.html shows up. So it seems there is some default rule defined already somewhere else.